# h:dataTable get specific ID

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable

im having a problem where i have printed out Snowboards in a datatable from a ArrayList. The problem is happening when i have a button that will be sent to a method and for now just system out it. When the button is clicked i get all the ids from the arraylist instead of just the specific one.

index.xhtml

```
<h:dataTable value="#{snowboardBean.snowList}" var="list">
                <h:column>
                    ID: #{list.id}<br></br>
                    Product Name: #{list.productName}<br></br>
                    Brand Name: #{list.brandName} <br></br>

                    <ui:param name="listID" value="#{list.id}" />

                    <h:button value="Test" onclick="#{snowboardBean.forwardId(listID)}" />
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
```

ForwardId() in the bean

```
public void forwardId(String productId){
    System.out.println("ForwardID");
    this.productId = productId;
    System.out.println(productId);
    System.out.println(this.productId);
}
```

Output like this after one click:
ForwardID
1
ForwardID
2

Comment: There are some strange points in your code. I remember that onclick event in <h:button> is "Javascript code executed when a pointer button is clicked over this element."

Comment: Don't quite get what you mean. The thing is the code is running and i get output but i get output from all IDs in the arraylist, not the specific one that want. And what are the other strange points that you mentioned?

Comment: You can replace <h:button> to <h:commandButton value="Test" action="#{snowboardBean.forwardId(list.id)}" />

Answer (score 0):

In your above XHTML you need not to create an param to send the id. Rather just replace you XHTML like below:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{snowboardBean.snowList}" var="list">
   <h:column>
      ID: #{list.id}<br></br>
      Product Name: #{list.productName}<br></br>
      Brand Name: #{list.brandName} <br></br>
      <h:commandButton value="Test" action="#{snowboardBean.forwardId(list.idD)}" />
   </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```